# Non-void function should return a value

Tags: ios, swift, return, uicollectionviewcell

I am currently trying to make a calendar and this error keeps on popping up.

I have tried return 0, and return `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {return 0}

   private func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {return }
```

Non-void function should return a value

Comment: `collectionView` is REQUIRED to return an instance `UICollectionViewCell`.  If there are 0 cells, then this will never be called, but you're implementation is still required to return something, because the compiler can't guarantee that the function will never be called.  Simply create an empty instance of `UICollectionViewCell` and return it to satisfy the compiler

Comment: Functions aren't like politicians. They actually have to answers the "questions" you pose to them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return 0 and UICollectionViewCell,
you should return them

Like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "nameOfIdentifier", for: indexPath) 
      return cell
}
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {return 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're using a `UICollectionView`, you might need to show atleast 1 `UICollectionViewCell` in it.

And for that very purpose there is `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods.

Returning `0` in `collectionView(_: numberOfItemsInSection:)` won't do anything useful. Its just like I've a `collectionView` and don't want to show anything in it (until and unless there are specific conditions to return 0).

So, the method must return the number of `cells` you want to show in the `collectionView`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Now comes the error you're facing: ***Non-void function should return a value***.

The error is because of another `UICollectionViewDataSource's` methods, i.e. `collectionView(_: cellForItemAt:)`. This method expects you to `return` the actual `collectionViewCell` that'll be visible in the `collectionView`.

In the code you added, you're only calling `return`. Instead you must `return` an instance of `UICollectionViewCell` like so,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```